# How do i automatically click the link while page loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need bit help about jquery...

I'm using woocommerce and i have to make contract texts visible but my theme makes it visible only when I click on the contract link and I want this link to be automatically clicked while the page is loading.

Before click contract link
https://prnt.sc/t7owcb

After click contract link
https://prnt.sc/t7ox49

How can I leave this field open?

Thank you!

Comment: `$('.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link').click();` should do it

Comment: I added your code to my theme's custom js but didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: @blex (Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function)

Comment: Then jquery is not loaded before you're executing the function or you have broken code before the function, because what he provided is valid jQuery syntax.

Comment: Instead of thinking in a step of clicking a button to display the contract link, why not skip that entirely and find the function that's triggered by that link and simply do that on DOM load ?

Comment: @Martin tbh i couldn't find that triggered function, that's why i thought i can do it with jquery

Comment: You can do it, but simply make sure that jquery is loaded in before trying to execute the click function. If it still doesn't work after that, then that means you have broken javascript code somewhere beforehand. Alternatively, put it into a document.ready block.

Comment: If jQuery isn't loaded, you can still do it without. But we need to make sure the DOM is fully loaded: `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { document.querySelector('.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link').click(); });`

Comment: Thank you guys. I tried your code @blex. The contract field is visible for 2 seconds after the page is loaded, but is hidden again later

Comment: It would be easier to debug and try stuff if we could see the code managing that behavior. I couldn't find a WooCommerce site with the feature you're describing. Are you able to share a link, either to your website, or one using the exact same functionnality?

Comment: Ok, could you try `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { document.querySelector('.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-wrapper').style.display = 'block'; });` (and remove any previous solution I gave you)

Comment: Update: I tried this code on my browser console and it's working when i add this code custom js, didn't work. I think because of domcontentloaded issue
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link').click();
  var body = $( 'body' );
});

Comment: @blex i added your last code. It looks for a few seconds but disappears again. You can see this when you refresh the page

Comment: Oh, I see why, now. There is an Ajax request which returns HTML and it's used to replace the previous "terms and conditions" we hide. I'm trying to think of a clean way to handle this

Comment: Ok, what about this? `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { var s = document.createElement('style'); s.innerText = '.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-wrapper{display: block!important;}'; document.body.appendChild(s); });`

Comment: @blex I tried every code of yours with great excitement and you did it :) It's working... Thanks to you, I solved an important problem in my project. You're amazing :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. I'll post it as an answer with a little explanation, in case others stumble upon this problem (GDPR...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, we found a way to show the terms and conditions by default on the checkout page.

We can't just show the div, or trigger a click, because the terms' wrapper element is overwritten after an Ajax request, so it removes anything we try to do before that.

But we can force `display: block` by adding a `<style>` tag to the page. That won't be overwritten, and by using `!important`, we make sure this gets higher priority in CSS:

```
// When the DOM is ready
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Create a style tag
  var s = document.createElement('style');
  s.innerText = '.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-wrapper{display: block!important;}';
  // Append it to the body
  document.body.appendChild(s);
});
```